# SharePoint 2010 REST in iOS returns bad URL

Tags: objective-c, rest, sharepoint

I'm trying to query a Sharepoint List using REST. It works in IE and Chrome but in iOS after sending async request it jumps directly to `didFailWithError` returning:

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1000 "bad URL" UserInfo=0xe95ba00 {NSUnderlyingError=0x8258680 "bad URL", NSLocalizedDescription=bad URL}
```

The REST code is:

```
@"http://mySP/site/siteColl/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/MyList?$filter=Infotyp eq 'NO'"
```

If I use:

```
@"http://mySP/site/siteColl/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/MyList"
```

instead, then everything is fine. Authorization is not an issue.
So why is the filter not working?

EDIT: Found out why. It's the spaces in the query. But how should I format them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it. Used `RESTQuery = [RESTQuery stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]` which returns a legal URL encoding